# Proof explanation on Dyadic forms a dense subset of $R$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

> [image]

This should be simple, but can someone explain how $1/q < \delta$ implies the inequality $$a - \delta < m/q < a < a - \delta?$$

Was a value of $\delta$ chosen here (say $m\delta = a)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is another way to look at it. The interval $[\frac{m}{q}, \frac{m+1}{q}]$ has length $\frac{1}{q}$. So, if we pick and element $a$ within that interval and look at a neighborhood around $a$ with a half-length greater than $\frac{1}{q}$ then is it clear how the inequalities follow?

Comment: Ah yes I knew this was obvious! Stepping $1/q$ units in a $1/q$ size interval ensures you have to leave the set.